# Use python client to create Kubernetes CronJob from yaml

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

I am trying to use the K8S python client to create a bunch of cronjobs on my cluster. I can't seem to find a `create_from_yaml` for cornjobs or any resources other than deployments for that matter. What I want to do is:

```
from kubernetes import client, utils

batchv1beta1 = client.BatchV1beta1Api()
utils.create_from_yaml(batchv1beta1, 'jobs/job-01.yaml')
```

But this doesn't work obviously since this is not a valid attribute. Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Actually, `utils.create_from_yaml` supports any Kubernetes objects. This should work:

```py
from kubernetes import client, utils 

k8s_client = client.ApiClient() 
utils.create_from_yaml(k8s_client, 'jobs/job-01.yaml')
```